# Why is SQL Server 2017 CU18 much slower than CU3 on update and insert commands (C# application, docker, debian 9/10)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, ado.net, sqlperformance

After migrating a SQL Server database to a new server we experienced a significant performance drop of 30 % to 500 % for sql update and insert commands on the client side and ran many configurations and tests in order to identify the source of the problem. It turned out to depend on the version of the SQL Server 2017: CU3 (fast) vs CU18 (slow).

The setting: 
SQL Server 2017 on linux.
C# winforms application using plain ADO.NET without entity framework.
Repeated tests with ubuntu 16.04 and debian 9 and 10 and on two different remote servers and with and without a docker container. Each server did not run any other task.

Time was measured (1) within the C# application and (2) using the regressed queries feature of the query store in SQL Server Management Studio. The increased duration did only occur for the total time measured within C# as follows:

```
long tStart = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // SqlCommand
long tEnd = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
```

Example results for debian 10, docker container, duration measured in C# code:

```
Update command 1 (updating 3 columns in 1 row for table with 1 row and 86 columns):
CU3:  20 ms
CU18: 92 ms (360 % slower)

Update command 2 (updating 74 columns in 1 row for table with 300 rows and 74 columns):
CU3:  28 ms
CU18: 60 ms (114 % slower)
```

The durations measured using the query store were around 0.3 ms for command 1 and 0.5 ms for command 2 independent of the SQL Server version CU3 and CU18. The duration of select commands was not affected very much.

My questions:

- Did anyone else experience such performance drops after upgrading the version of the SQL Server on linux?
- Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: For your first question, **Yes, I have experienced such performance drops after upgrading the version of the SQL Server on Linux** - For your second question, **I have absolutely no idea.. Sorry.**

Comment: I just found a link to a **Microsoft** page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056498/cumulative-update-4-for-sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks, Momoro! Good to know, that I am not the only one experiencing the performance drop. Is a certain information of the Microsoft page important or just the page as a whole?

Comment: Ah, **I'd say as a whole..**

Comment: I created a bug report: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39683227-why-is-sql-server-2017-cu18-much-slower-than-cu3-o

Comment: That's **great!** I hope they fix it **soon!**